# How to config a storybook for a ui library for Ionic & Angular

Tags: angular, storybook, ionic5

I'm developing a library with some ui components for Ionic 5 & Angular 11, and I would like to configure my first storybook to develop and document the library.
My lib doesn't have an AppController, but has only a module with a button component.

Here my stories file:

```
export default {
  title: 'AlertButtonComponent',
};

export const primary = () => ({
  moduleMetadata: {
    declarations: [AlertButtonComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
  },
  component: AlertButtonComponent,
  props: {
    label: text('label', 'Button Label'),
    message: text('message', 'Alert message!'),
  },
});
```

In the storybook the button works, but the style is not 100% like when is placed inside an Ionic app:

[image]

I saw that on a normal app, Ionic apply some base css rules to the body tag, but how can achieve that?
Probably I need something like a parent App container to my button component, but how can I do that if I'm developing only a library?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work?

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import Button from './button.component';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button2',
  component: Button,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot()],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<Button> = (args: Button) => ({
  component: Button,
  props: args,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  label: 'Next',
  message: 'Alert Message',
};
```

Comment: Hi Aaron! I saw that on the storybook website there are some examples like this but with a syntax a bit different. I already tested it and the result is the same...

Comment: I ran this code and it works fine so you need to provide code specific to your component